# How can I start learning mathematics for machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, math

I am an Android programmer. Now, I would like to learn machine learning. I know it requires a mathematical background, like statistics, probability, calculus and linear algebra. However, I am a bit lost. Where should I start from? Can someone provide me a road map for how to learn the mathematical background required for machine learning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should begin from Dr Andrew Ng machine learning course on Coursera. It's probably the most popular course for newcomers in machine learning. It's a free course.

You should also grab "Elements of Statistical Learning" ebook PDF. It's a free book.

You may want to focus on:

1. Regression
2. Cross validation
3. Bias-variance tradeoff
4. Decision surface
5. Gradient descent

And more...

Answer (score 2):

Some of the fundamental mathematical concepts required in ML field are as follows:

- Linear Algebra
- Analytic Geometry
- Matrix Decompositions
- Vector Calculus
- Probability and Distribution
- Continuous Optimization

A very recent book availble at [Mathematics for Machine Learning](https://mml-book.github.io/) covers all these aspects and more.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested to deepen your statistical concepts before diving into machine learning, i would recommend **Introduction to Statistics: Descriptive Statistics** course in **edX**

where you'll learn

- The fundamental concepts and methods of statistics
- How to intepret graphical and numerical summaries of data
- Understand the reasoning behind the calculations, the assumptions under which    they are valid, and the correct interpretation of results

The link for course is [edX](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-statistics-descriptive-uc-berkeleyx-stat2-1x)

This will definitely clarify your stat background with added benefit of certification.