# Which introductory courses (preferably video lectures) could I use to learn ML for applying ML to black hole simulations?

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request

I am a Ph.D. candidate in High Energy Physics and my research involves numerical simulations and data analysis. I am interested to learn Artificial Intelligence and Machine Learning from the basics so that I could implement the same in my research. Due to the huge popularity of AI & ML one could easily find a large number of articles on the internet on the topic, but it seems to me that a search for a proper course (that would teach the basics at the beginner level) is nearly impossible for me.

It would be helpful if someone suggest me an introductory course (preferably video lecture) on 'machine learning' with the goal of applying the concepts to simulations of black hole environments.

Comment: Hello. Please, reformulate the question so that it's not too broad. If you're looking for courses (with video lessons) on a specific subject (e.g. "introduction to machine learning"), then that should be your **specific** question. Asking for resources on AI and ML is **too broad** (because there are many types of resources, many subjects in AI and ML, etc.), so this post could be closed as such.

Comment: @nbro Thanks for the suggestion. I had reformulated the question. My interest is on implementation of AI in numerical simulations of black hole environments that include hydrodynamics around black holes.

Comment: Ok, thanks for trying to improve this post. I would also suggest that you put your **specific** question in the title. Right now, you still have a quite broad title and you still left "any introductory course, lecture notes or lecture videos on 'machine learning' suitable for the beginners" in your post, so the post is still a bit broad.

Comment: It may be a good idea to reformulate your question as something like "Which resources (in particular, courses with video lessons) could I use to study machine learning for the ultimate purpose of applying ML to simulations of black holes" (if this is your question, I don't know for sure)

Comment: In addition to that, this type of question has been asked a lot here in the past. For example, [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/3374/2444), [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/3548/2444), [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/3291/2444), or [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/4509/2444). As you can see, one person already provided an answer, which can be useful, but shows that your post is too broad.

Comment: I have edited your post to focus on 1. ML, 2. courses and 3. beginners, so that your post is more focused and thus acceptable now. In any case, I still think your question is a bit too broad and partially a duplicate of the linked ones. It may also be a good idea to provide an example of a course that you found and that is "not suitable for beginners" or more specifically you, in order to understand which courses you're really looking for.

Comment: @nbro Thank you for the clarification. Actually I am completely new to the subject and I am yet to learn ML. I had started with Andrew Ng's course.

Comment: @nbro on what grounds this is *not* an opinion-based question (hence closable as such)?

Comment: @desertnaut The OP is looking for one course that meets certain requirements (i.e. for beginners, that covers machine learning, preferably with the "goal of applying the concepts to simulations of black hole environments.". So, it seems to me that this is the type of question is similar to a question like "Which model could I use for this problem X?". In other words, the OP is looking for one possible solution to their problem, not necessarily the "best", which would make it opinion-based, as "best" is ambiguous or relative. We had many similar questions in the past...

Comment: In many cases, this type of question doesn't lead to "good" answers. So, in a way, you're right, this might lead to opinions, but, hopefully, people will provide references that meet the requirements rather than based on their preferences or opinions. If you want, we can discuss this topic more on meta. Feel free to create a meta post so that we can discuss there, and see what the community thinks about this type of question.

Answer (score 2):

Cornell University offers lecture notes and videos of over thirty machine learning related courses in this [link](https://research.cs.cornell.edu/machinelearning/pages/courses.php). CS4780 Introduction to Machine Learning in particular is a great resource ([lecture notes](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4780/2021fa/), [recordings](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl8OlHZGYOQ7bkVbuRthEsaLr7bONzbXS)).

The Visual Computing Group of TU Munich also offers lecture notes and videos of modern computer vision related tasks in this [link](https://www.niessnerlab.org/teaching.html). Introduction to Deep Learning in particular is a great resource ([lecture notes](https://niessner.github.io/I2DL/), [recordings](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQ8Y4kIIbzy_OaXv86lfbQwPHSomk2o2e)). There are also courses on advanced topics of deep learning, image segmentation, 3D scanning, as well as a lot of publications on scene reconstruction, simulations and more.